Keep old url but redirect to new url - IIS - Asp.Net - .aspx
Running - IIS 10 - Asp.Net - Web Forms "Web Application" - .Net Framework 4.8
WebAppDemo is a web forms "application" under "Default Web Site"
Default Web Site

    WebAppDemo

Allows only a http:80 binding on default port 80.
Users use this url to access this web application like so - http://webappdemo.domain.com/Default.aspx
Now, we want to create a "New Site" and only allow a  https:9443 binding on a custom port :9443 (for example).
This "New Site" will contain the WebAppDemo as an application under it
New Site

    WebAppDemo

Now, I want the users to keep using the old URL which is http://webappdemo.domain.com/Default.aspx but be served/redirected to https://webappdemo.domain.com:9443/Default.aspx
Note the https: and the port # 9443 in the new URL.
Update:
Looks like it is URL-Rewrite module that i will need.
However, I don't want the redirect rule apply for the entire "Default Web Site" I just want to redirect a specific application's Urls such as http://dev-abc-xyz.myorg.com/WebAppDemo/<rest of the url> and redirect them to https://dev-abc-xyz.myorg.com:9443/WebAppDemo/<rest of the url>

Use IIS's URL Rewrite feature - no point doing it from within old ASP.NET code.

Posting the same question multiple times or on different sites won’t take you any further if you just don’t follow any advice.

@LexLi  in my question above, i have provided a specific option that i want to use. if you have any information to share with regards to that, please do so. otherwise with all due respect, please keep your rants to yourself.

You only revealed your option a few minutes ago if you didn't have good memory.

The same question you already posted here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/1692582/keep-old-url-but-redirect-to-new-url-iis-asp-net-a?orderby=helpful.
